# How do I programmatically edit the body of a block?

Tags: drupal-7, hook, auto-update

I have a block which contains a copyright date in the body.

Ex:

```
© 2017 Some Company
```

However, I want to be able code the year to auto-update rather than having to manually change it every time. I can't use the PHP filter module.

Would I create my own module and run a specific hook?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Tokens module. Create a Tokens text format and use it for the block text. Then insert the token "[current-date:custom:Y]" for the year.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dedicated block in your custom module, then style the output using its block template and CSS, etc:

```php
<?php
function YOURMODULE_block_info() {
  $blocks['copyright'] = array(
    'info' => t('Copyright'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL,
    'properties' => array(
      'administrative' => TRUE,
    )
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function YOURMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'copyright':
      $block['subject'] = '';
      $block['content'] = array(
        '#markup' => t('© !YEAR Some Company', array('!YEAR' => date('Y'))),
      );
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```